# Erratic behavior of EntityManager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, entitymanager, hibernate-entitymanager

long time browser first time asker.

I'm facing several problems with my application, and I don't know if they have something in common, the thing that baffles me is that they don't happen regularly or with a pattern, sometimes is one entity sometimes is another, at times the same request separated by seconds produces a different outcome.
The problemes are these:

1. When I retrieve an entity it comes with some attributes correct(id) and others *null*, so when I evaluate if the entity is *null* it returns *false*, but when I try to work with one of the attributes it generates an *null pointer exception*
2. When I try to get a relation it returns *null*, this I solved by fetching the relation with the query, but I can't use that solution everywhere
3. Sometimes the entityManager closes with no explanation whatsoever, I check if the session is open to opening it otherwise, however it evaluates as true but in the next line of code where I try to perform an operation it throws an *session closed* error
4. Sometimes when I save a child Entity it throws a *null pointer exception* on the parent entity

Notes about my implementation:

1. All relations are lazy
2. No toString method has any relations in it
3. I'm using CriteriaBuilder for my queries
4. I'm using EntityManager to persist my entities
5. One of my pending tasks is to save changes to several entities in the same transaction, so in the following code that's something I have present

Employee Entity

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_id_employees", sequenceName = "seq_id_employees",
                initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
@Entity
@Table(name = "Employees")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_id_employees")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
    .
    .
    .    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "employee")
    private EmployeeDetail empDetails;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "employee")
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();
    .
    .
    .
    public EmployeeDetail getEmpDetails() {
        return empDetails;
    }

    public void setEmpDetails(EmployeeDetail empDetails) {
        this.empDetails = empDetails;
    }
    .
    .
    .
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "EmployeesEntity [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", picture=" + Arrays.toString(picture)
                + ", companyMail=" + companyMail + ", active=" + active + ", maxAuth=" + maxAuth + ", created="
                + created + ", updated=" + updated + "]";
    }
}
```

EmployeeDetail Entity

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_id_emp_details", sequenceName = "seq_id_emp_details",
                initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee_Details")
public class EmployeeDetail implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_id_emp_details")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;
    .
    .
    .
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
    private Employee employee;
    .
    .
    .
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
    .
    .
    .
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

}
```

EmployeeDaoImp

```
public class EmployeeDaoImp extends BaseDaoImp<Employee, Long> implements BaseDao<Employee> {


    /**
     * @Function saveOrUpdate
     * @EmployeesEntity employeeEntity
     * @return blResult
     * @type boolean
     */
    @Override
    public boolean saveOrUpdate(Employee entity) {

        boolean blResult = false;

        try {
            entTransaction.begin();
            if(entity.getId() == 0){
                entManager.persist(entity);
            } else {
                entManager.merge(entity);
            }
            entTransaction.commit();
            blResult = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if(entTransaction.isActive()) {
                entTransaction.rollback();
            }
            entManager.clear();
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return blResult;
    }


    /**
     * @Function delete
     * @EmployeesEntity employeeEntity
     * @return blResult
     * @type boolean
     */
    @Override
    public boolean delete(Employee employeeEntity) {

        boolean blResult = false;

        try {
            //openEntManager();
            entTransaction.begin();
            entManager.remove(employeeEntity);
            entTransaction.commit();
            blResult = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if(entTransaction.isActive()) {
                entTransaction.rollback();
            }
            entManager.clear();
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return blResult;
    }


    /**
     * @Function getById
     * @long lngEmployeeId
     * @return employeeEntity
     * @type EmployeesEntity
     */
    @Override
    public Employee getById(long lngEmployeeId) {

        Employee employeeEntity = null;

        try {

            CriteriaBuilder cBuilder = entManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<Employee> cQuery = cBuilder.createQuery(Employee.class);
            Root<Employee> root = cQuery.from(Employee.class);
            cQuery.where(cBuilder.equal(root.get("id"), lngEmployeeId));

            TypedQuery<Employee> tQuery = entManager.createQuery(cQuery);
            List<Employee> employeesList = tQuery.getResultList();
            if (!employeesList.isEmpty()) {
                employeeEntity = employeesList.get(0);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return employeeEntity;
    }


    /**
     * @Function getList
     * @return employeesList
     * @type List<EmployeesEntity>
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Employee> getList() {

        List<Employee> employeesList = new ArrayList<Employee>();

        try {
            CriteriaBuilder cBuilder = entManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<Employee> cQuery = cBuilder.createQuery(Employee.class);
            Root<Employee> root = cQuery.from(Employee.class);
            List<Order> listOrder = new ArrayList<Order>();
            listOrder.add(cBuilder.desc(root.get("id")));
            cQuery.orderBy(listOrder);
            cQuery = this.searchParameters(cBuilder, cQuery, root);

            TypedQuery<Employee> tQuery = entManager.createQuery(cQuery);
            employeesList = tQuery.getResultList();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return employeesList;
    }


    /**
     * @Function search
     * @long lngEmployeeId
     * @long lngPositionId
     * @int intActive
     * @return employeesList
     * @type List<EmployeesEntity>
     */
    public List<Employee> search(long lngEmployeeId, long lngPositionId, int intActive) {

        List<Employee> employeesList = new ArrayList<Employee>();

        try {

            CriteriaBuilder cBuilder = entManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<Employee> cQuery = cBuilder.createQuery(Employee.class);
            Root<Employee> root = cQuery.from(Employee.class);
            root.fetch("empDetails"); //Solution problem 2

            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
            List<Order> listOrder = new ArrayList<Order>();
            listOrder.add(cBuilder.desc(root.get("id")));
            cQuery.orderBy(listOrder);

            if (lngEmployeeId > 0) {
                predicates.add(cBuilder.equal(root.get("id"), lngEmployeeId));
            }
            if (lngPositionId > 0) {
                predicates.add(cBuilder.equal(root.get("position").get("id"), lngPositionId));
            }
            if (intActive < 2) {
                predicates.add(cBuilder.equal(root.get("active"), intActive));
            }
            cQuery.select(root).where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {}));

            TypedQuery<Employee> tQuery = entManager.createQuery(cQuery);
            employeesList = tQuery.getResultList();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return employeesList;
    }
}
```

I'm omitting further DaoImps as they all follow the same structure

Basic Example Code problem 1

```
EmployeeDaoImp employeesDao = new EmployeeDaoImp();
Employee employee = employeesDao.getById(1);
String newName = "Some Name";
boolean sameName = false;

if(employee != null){
    if(employee.getName().equals(newName)){ //SOMETIMES this throws the exception and debugging shows Name attribute to be null
        sameName = true;
    }
}
```

Basic Example Code problem 2

```
EmployeeDaoImp employeesDao = new EmployeeDaoImp();
employeesDao.addOrderBy("id", "desc");
List<Employee> employeesList = employeesDao.getList();
List<String> phoneList = new ArrayList<String>();

for (Employee employee : employeesList) {
    EmployeeDetail details = employee.getEmpDetails();

    phoneList.add(details.getPhone()); //SOMETIMES this throws null pointer exception, it is avoidable if I use the root.fetch as seen on EmployeeDaoImp file
}
```

Basic Example Code problem 4

```
String strNewName = request.getParameter("newName");
String strNewPhone = request.getParameter("newPhone");
long lngEmployeeId = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("employeeId"));

EmployeeDaoImp employeeDao = new EmployeeDaoImp();
EmployeeDetailDaoImp employeeDetailDao = new EmployeeDetailDaoImp();
Employee employee = employeeDao.getById(lngEmployeeId);
employee.setName(strNewName);

boolean result = false;
if (employeeDao.saveOrUpdate(employee)) {
    EmployeeDetail details = employee.getEmpDetails();
    details.setPhone(strNewPhone);
    if(employeeDetailDao.saveOrUpdate(details)){ //SOMETIMES this throws null pointer exception regarding the parent(Employee)
        result = true;
    }
}
```

BaseDaoImp & problem #3 example on *openEntManager* method

```
public class BaseDaoImp <T, ID extends Serializable> {

    private static EntityManagerFactory emFactory;

    static {emFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("com.daoImp");}

    protected static EntityManager entManager  = emFactory.createEntityManager();

    protected static EntityTransaction entTransaction = entManager.getTransaction();

    private List<String[]> orderBy = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    private List<String[]> conditions = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    private List<String> relations = new ArrayList<String>();


    /**
     * @brief BaseDaoImpl class constructor, manages a session in database
     */
    public BaseDaoImp() {
        if(!entManager.isOpen()) {
            entManager = emFactory.createEntityManager();
        }
    }
    .
    .
    .

    public void closeEntManager() {
        try {
            entManager.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }

    public void openEntManager() {
        try {
            if(!entManager.isOpen()) {
                entManager = emFactory.createEntityManager();
            }
            entManager.clear(); //SOMETIMES this throws session closed error
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        try {
            entManager.clear();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

Additional notes:

1. The *clearCache* method I use only when a User logs successfully to extract the data directly from the database and not the first level cache
2. The *openEntManager* method is just for testing purposes, is not used beyond that
3. This is my first experience with Spring / Hibernate, so, any pointers and criticism are welcome
4. In the database all the required registers exist for the function of a correct implementation, which obviously mine is not
5. Sorry if my english or redaction is bad

Answer (score 0):

For the problem 1, although your employee object is not null, but the property "name" maybe sometimes null, then null doesn't have the method equals(), null pointer exception will be thrown

Comment: Not the case, the fields on the database are not null and this exception gets thrown regardless
Yes, I have some null fields but those are handled acordingly